# URL Structure - advise and thoughts of best approach?

Tags: url, structure, seo

I am currently building a website for Hot Tubs and within this there will be New Tubs, Used Tubs and Hire Tubs (each will be a top level page on the navigation, and each tub will have a details page). Each tub will only exist in one of the three sections. The templates will be different and so I have decided to go for 3 individual channels.

However, any thoughts from a URL structure/SEO etc on the different approaches to URLS for sections.
I am thinking of either keeping them all separate like so:

```
www.domain.co.uk/used-hot-tubs/  
www.domain.co.uk/used-hot-tubs/name-of-used-tub/ 

www.domain.co.uk/hot-tubs/  
www.domain.co.uk/hot-tubs/name-of-new-tub/  

www.domain.co.uk/hot-tubs-for-hire/  
www.domain.co.uk/hot-tubs-for-hire/name-of-hire-tub/
```

Or whether they should all be structure like so?

```
www.domain.co.uk/hot-tubs/used/  
www.domain.co.uk/hot-tubs/used/name-of-used-tub/

www.domain.co.uk/hot-tubs/new/  
www.domain.co.uk/hot-tubs/new/name-of-new-tub/ 

www.domain.co.uk/hot-tubs/hire/  
www.domain.co.uk/hot-tubs/hire/name-of-hire-tub/
```

or

```
www.domain.co.uk/used/
www.domain.co.uk/used/name-of-used-tub/

www.domain.co.uk/new/
www.domain.co.uk/new/name-of-new-tub/

www.domain.co.uk/hire/
www.domain.co.uk/hire/name-of-hire-tub/
```

Any input/thoughts appreciated….

EDIT: I should add this is not an eCommerce website, although the structure could lends itself to that and that the top level domain does contain the words hottubs.

Answer (score 3):

I’d go for /hot-tubs/used etc

This way you can also have /accessories/pipes etc

Answer (score 3):

The general rule of thumb is to start with the most general thing, and end in the most specific thing. The nice part of this is that it makes sense to humans, too.

I'd go with `/hot-tubs/new/name-of-hot-sub` for that reason... in addition to reading well (just from the URL, you know what it is), you'll have more flexibility in the future.

Try to have your page `<title>`s and `<h1>` or other semantic tags mirror this pattern.